# Browsing from Firefox Geckodriver with proxy. C#, Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

using the code below i'm trying to set up Selenium to work with Geckodriver using custom ssl proxy.

```
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.SslProxy = "213.232.68.107:8000";
    options.Proxy = proxy;
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

But, unfortunatly, it still uses direct connection, without any redirections.

Other way was to configure proxy using this part of code,

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();         
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");     
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 3128);
```

But, start of the browser failed with expection:

`"The type initializer for 'System.IO.Compression.ZipStorer' threw an exception."`

`NotSupportedException: No data is available for encoding 437`

No info was found about all of this stuff. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, managed to make it work just to switching from .net core into .net framework using this code

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.http", "213.232.68.107");
    profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 8000);
    options.Profile = profile;
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```